# Вопрос о синтаксисе наследования, где суперкласс параметризован

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Хотел спросить на счет синтаксиса при наследовании от парметризованного класса.

Имеется класс (суперкласс) дерево, в вершинах которого хранятся пары ключ-значение (`template <class K, class V>`). И написать я хочу производный класс, который будет уже иметь не а `<K, V>`, а `<String, V>`

Вопрос в том, как правильно оформить это наследование.

Например, как оформить конструктор класса? Правилен ли такой вариант:

```
class_name () : Tree<String, T> () {}
```

?

Comment: Вы когда унаследуете класс, потом будете просто писать `class_name () : Tree() {}`, здесь `Tree` будет injected-name и указывать у него аргументы шаблона необязательно, как собственно и у `class_name ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычное наследование. Но поскольку у вас все равно остается один параметр типа - то это будет шаблонный класс.

[Например](https://ideone.com/OfrCnr):

```
template<typename Second>
class myPair: public pair<int,Second>
{
public:
    myPair(const Second& s = Second(), int j = 0)
    :pair<int,Second>(j,s)
    {}

    void out() const
    { cout
        << "(" << this->first
        << ":" << this->second << ")\n";
    }

};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    myPair<double> d(3.1415926);
    myPair<string> s("Hello",3);

    d.out();
    s.out();

}
```

Мне удалось вам ответить или нужно что-то подробнее пояснить?

Comment: Премного благодарен.

Comment: Если устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый.

Comment: Не менее любопытный вопрос: как закрывать вопросы в SO?

Comment: Слева от ответа есть счетчик плюсов и минусов за ответ. Но если вы - автор вопроса, то там еще есть такая "псиса", щелчок на которой делает ее зеленой, а вопрос - имеющим принятый ответ.